# How to do a full match search with two parameters?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have database model

```
Schema({
  members: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
    required: true
  },
  lastMessage: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    from: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: [
    {
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      message: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      from: {
        type: String,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

That code I use to find some documents

```
Chats.countDocuments(
      {
        members: {
          $in: ["userIdOne", "userIdTwo"]
        }
      },
      cb
    )
```

I use `$in` to find data what I need, but `$in` find all documents which contains one of this **userId...**. Me need to find only one document which contains that user's ids.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) instead

```
Chats.countDocuments(
  {
    members: {
      $all: ["userIdOne", "userIdTwo"]
    }
  },
  cb
)
```

Comment: @bpGusar if you need exact match, this answer can give wrong results. See [playgound](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SF8G351L3Sk). It will match the documents also with members ["userIdOne", "userIdTwo","userIdThree"]

Comment: @Valijon yes you are right, but there is no harm to mention about this

Comment: @bpGusar if this answer solves your problem, please don't fotget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact match, you can use [$setEquals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/#exp._S_setEquals) aggregation operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $setEquals: [
              "$members",
              [
                "userIdOne",
                "userIdTwo"
              ]
            ]
          },
          true
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "count"
  }
])
```

Input:

```
[
  {
    "members": [
      "userIdOne"
    ]
  },
  {
    "members": [
      "userIdTwo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "members": [
      "userIdOne",
      "userIdTwo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "members": [
      "userIdOne",
      "userIdTwo",
      "userIdThere"
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4KiHtAR5Z3F)

You can integrate this to mongoose like this:

```js
  const result = await Chats.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            {
              $setEquals: ["$members", ["userIdOne", "userIdTwo"]]
            },
            true
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $count: "count"
    }
  ]);

  const count = result[0].count;
```

Comment: `$setEquals` has some defects like this: `{ $setEquals: [ [ "a", "b", "a" ], [ "b", "a" ] ] }  => true`

Comment: @Valijon thank you pointing this. But I guess userId's will not have duplicate values.